# Toast showing or popping up 3x

Tags: android, android-layout, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Good day, do you guys know how to fix my toast? It pops out "Record Updated", "Email Auth Updated" even tho there's only one.
here's my code for it. I have no really idea if it's the toast or the realtime database that makes it popping out 3x. Thank you.

```
changeprofile_savechanges.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FirebaseAuth userAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        final String firebaseUser = userAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser);
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.exists()){
                    String roles = snapshot.child("userType").getValue().toString();
                    if(roles.equals("admin")){
                        final String updatedFullName = changeFullName.getText().toString().trim();
                        final String updatedUserEmail = changeEmailUser.getText().toString().trim();
                        final String updatedPhoneNumber = changePhoneNumber.getText().toString().trim();
                        databaseReference.child("fullName").setValue(updatedFullName);
                        databaseReference.child("userEmail").setValue(updatedUserEmail);
                        databaseReference.child("phoneNumber").setValue(updatedPhoneNumber);
                        Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this, "Record Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        FirebaseUser adminUser =  FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                        adminUser.updateEmail(updatedUserEmail).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this, "Email Auth Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

after it logging it back, since it re-authenticate when i had to change my email the toast are popping out 3x and it's annoying and I really have no clue about it on how to fix it.

Comment: up, anyone who could help me with this one ?